# Why my Angular js code is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is my code for angular js and html.Please help me about this.why it is not working with file if any error in syntax in html file or angular file?
I am trying to make a order table and I am doing it using angular js method and every time when I runs it on browser the Angular code is not working and Add button is also not working for me which is used to add the more entities in order.

```js
angular.module('Commande', [])
    .controller('commandeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.articles = [
                { id: 1, reference: 123, titre: "MSI GTX 980ti", prixUnitaire: 666.63, quantite: 0, montantHT: 666.63, montantTTC: 799.95 },
                { id: 2, reference: 456, titre: "Intel Core i7-4770K", prixUnitaire: 324.96, quantite: 0, montantHT: 324.96, montantTTC: 389.95 },
                { id: 3, reference: 789, titre: "ASUS MAXIMUS VII RANGER", prixUnitaire: 134.96, quantite: 0, montantHT: 134.96, montantTTC: 161.95 }
        ];



        $scope.PrixTotalTTC = function() {
            var resultTTC = 0;

            angular.forEach($scope.articles, function (article) {
                resultTTC += article.montantTTC * article.quantite;
            });
            return resultTTC;
        };

        $scope.PrixTotalHT = function() {
            var resultHT = 0;

            angular.forEach($scope.articles, function (article) {
                resultHT += article.montantHT * article.quantite;
            });
            return resultHT;
        };

        $scope.NombreArticle = function() {
            var resultArticle = 0;

            angular.forEach($scope.articles, function(article){
                resultArticle += article.quantite;
            });
            return resultArticle;
        };

        $scope.AjouterArticle = function() {
            $scope.articles.push({
                id: '',
                reference: '',
                titre: '',
                prixUnitaire: 0,
                quantite: 0,
                montantHT: 0,
                montantTTC: 0
            });
        };

        $scope.SupprimerArticle = function(index) {
            $scope.articles.splice(index, 1);
        };

    }]);
```

```html
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="Commande" ng-controller="commandeController">
<h1>Bon de commande</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Référence</th>
                        <th>Titre</th>
                        <th>Prix unitaire HT/€</th>
                        <th>Quantité</th>
                        <th>Montant HT/€</th>
                        <th>Montant TTC/€</th>
                        <th>Supprimer</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="article in articles">
                        <th>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="article.id" class="form-control bfh-number" placeholder="Id" min=0>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="article.reference" class="form-control bfh-number" placeholder="Référence" min=0>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="article.titre" class="form-control" placeholder="Titre">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="article.prixUnitaire" class="form-control bfh-number">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="article.quantite" class="form-control bfh-number" min=0>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="article.montantHT" class="form-control bfh-number" min=0>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" ng-model="article.montantTTC" class="form-control bfh-number" min=0>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href ng:click="SupprimerArticle($index)"><i class="fa fa-times delete"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <th class="success">TOTAL</th>
                        <td class="success"></td>
                        <td class="success"></td>
                        <td class="success"></td>
                        <td class="success">{{ NombreArticle() }} article(s)</td>
                        <td class="success" ng-style="PrixTotalHT() >= 1000 && {'font-weight': 'bold'}">{{ PrixTotalHT() | number:2 }} €</td>
                        <td class="success" ng-style="PrixTotalHT() >= 1000 && {'font-weight': 'bold'}">{{ PrixTotalTTC() | number:2 }} €</td>
                        <td class="success"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href ng:click="AjouterArticle()" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter un article <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is my code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers : Welcome to Stack overflow. Please read this. :https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Its work here when I run code snippet but not working in my editor.

Comment: You should explain in greater detail what you want to get, and what the code gets as it is.

Comment: My code work here on StackOverflow when I Run Code snippet.

Comment: But when I run on the editor {{ NombreArticle() }} article(s) {{ PrixTotalHT() | number:2 }} € {{ PrixTotalTTC() | number:2 }} €

Comment: This comes on the bottom of table and also ajouter button do not works.

Comment: It do not allows me to add another product to table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a **content management system** (**CMS**), such as MAMP, XAMPP or similar. You basically need to run a local server for JavaScript code to work (as well as any PHP you might use). Simple solution, if just need JavaScript, is to use Node.js.

Comment: Hi @AlekseySolovey , Angular is for front end single page application.I think I have entered some wrong in head to get cdn integration of Ajs.

Comment: you can always download angularjs and import manually as a script, but if your code works here I would imagine that you need a local server